# How can you get a prototype member function (C++ -> Javascript)

Tags: c++, com, atl, idispatch

Does anyone know how you can call a method of a prototype in Javascript from C++?

I have an pointer to script IDispatch, and I can get the IDsOfNames for the prototype, but I can't find how to get the IDispatch of it's member function.

Say (pseudocode):

```
JSprototype foo
{
    method bar(baz);
}
```

I can get a valid DISPID of foo, but I don't know how to call `bar(baz)`. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: I'm assuming MSHTML, considering that you have an `IDispatch`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's what [`IDispatch::Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221479.aspx) is for. You don't need a separate `IDispatch` for every function. However, you *do* need a DISPID of `bar`, and therefore an `IDispatch` of `foo`. That means you'll have to call `iFoo->Invoke(DISPID_bar)` and `QueryInterface(IDispatch)` the result.

Comment: Yes, MSHTML. But I don't have a IDispatch of foo, I cant Invoke0(Bar, Baz); All I have is a IDispatch of the whole script object, and I can get DISPID of foo. How do you convert DISPID to IDispatch?

Comment: Generally speaking you can just do a PROPERTYGET with the DISPID of foo to get the IDispatch for foo.